# mongod stuck on fork with no error message

Tags: mongodb

I was unable to run mongod as a background process. There were no errors and the program got stuck after printing the following message:

> about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.

Here is the content of the specified *mongodb.conf*:

```
# See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration for format details
# Run mongod --help to see a list of options

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
port = 27027
quiet = true
fork = true
logpath = /home/mljli/proj/log/mongod.log
dbpath = /home/mljli/proj/db
logRotate = reopen
logappend = true
noscripting = true
noauth = true
```

Port 27027 was not used according to the output of *netstat*. *dbpath* exists and *logpath* is not a directory. I also tried the following simple configuration and it didn't work either:

```
$ mongod --fork --logpath mongod.log
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
```

Using sudo does not help.

My MongoDB version:

```
db version v3.4.3
git version: f07437fb5a6cca07c10bafa78365456eb1d6d5e1  
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Comment: The `--fork` behavior is as expected. Might need to tap enter once or twice. Check and you should see a `mongod` process running. As for the `.conf` file, When running under an init process or sysctl or similar scheme, then you should **not** specify the `fork` option in the configuration. Those tools will "daemonize" for you

Comment: @NeilLunn Nope. Typing enter does not help. The program just hangs and no other messages output.

Comment: I'm sorry. This bug happens on Arch only and there's already a [bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/50302) about this.